# How to install wlan driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have the drivers for a Broadcom wlan card, I just don't know how to do any of it. I will post a link to he read me file from Broadcom to see if anybody knows how to help.

here is a link to the [read me](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt)

I also have the tar.gz file on the desktop as a simple address.

Edit: i have tried this:sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

and it says my drivers are up to date but I still have no wireless

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue. <askubuntu.com/questions/425155/…; Not all broadcom cards are covered by additional drivers and many say they are but it is still the wrong driver, it is best to find out which wireless card you have before we tell you how to solve you problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a LAN connection or net access by other means, why don't you try installing the Broadcom drivers from the official repository? Go to the *Dash* by clicking the first icon on the left sidebar, type 'Sources' and click on the Sources app. (Or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `software-properties-gtk` and press enter.) It contains a tab called *Additional Drivers*, which should list the Broadcom driver. Enable it, and enter your password when asked for it.

Or, if you're comfortable with the terminal, open it and try:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you have already tried the official repository, and it didn't work, please edit your question to mention this.